# Обработка входящих сообщений Telegram API

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграмм бота для регистрации задач. Использую библиотеку от rubenlagus. Возникла проблема с обработкой входящих сообщений.
Метод: `public void onUpdateReceived(Update update){}`, позволяет обрабатывать каждое отдельное сообщение, вызывать другие методы после получения сообщения к примеру "/newtask", но как сделать так, чтобы после отправки команды боту - бот ожидал следующее сообщение и записывал этот текст например в переменную.
Пример диалога:
User: /newtask
Bot: Введите название задачи
User: Записаться к врачу.
Фразу: "Записаться к врачу", нужно записать в переменную.

Comment: Я по Python, но, я думаю что и у Java библиотек для Telegram есть штука под названием FSM. Погугли, должна быть либа с этим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В простейшей реализации, можете завести список с идентификаторами пользователей, для которых актива команда `/newtask` (ожидается ввод текста).

from scratch (в классе бота):

```java
    private List<Integer> processingUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    private void handleNewTaskCommand(Update update) {
        processingUsers.add(update.getMessage().getFrom().getId());
        sendPromtToChat(update);
    }

    private void handleSimpleMessage(Update update) {
        Integer userId = update.getMessage().getFrom().getId();
        if (processingUsers.contains(userId)) {
            doSomeWithTextForUser(update);
            processingUsers.remove(userId);
        }
    }
```

Если в методе `onUpdateReceived()` определяете, что пришла команда `/newtask`, то предаете в `handleNewTaskCommand()`, где id пользователя добавится в список активных (`processingUsers`);

Если в методе `onUpdateReceived()` определяете, что пришел обычный текст, то передаете update в `handleSimpleMessage()`, где проверяется, не ожидется ли в данный момент для данного пользователя ввода данных. Если ожидается, удаляете пользователя из спика и производите необходимые вам действия с текстом.

Данная реализация не претендует на лучшую, но для разбора работы бота из библиотеки и api телеграма для дальнейшего планирования приложения будет достаточно.

Так же обратите внимание, что в пришедшем `Update` может не оказаться "обычного" сообщения (см. в `Update` поля `editedMessage`, `channelPost` и т.д.), тогда вызов
 `getFrom()` выбросит NPE. Поэтому прежде чем процессить Update, желательно сначала проверить что он из себя представляет и что в нем в принципе содержится.